# Add a string at the beginning of the file with OPEN CLOSE function in Perl

Tags: perl

My code did not work for my any modifications. other than append nothing works for in open close functions.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl 
my $file = 'test'; 
open(INFO, $file); 
print INFO "Add this line please\n"; 
print INFO "First line\n"; 
close(INFO);
```

Comment: [perlfaq5 - How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f)

Comment: `use strict;` `use warnings;` Every. Time.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell perl what type of filehandle you want

```
open(INFO, ">", "$file")|| die "Cannot open $file";
```

This will create and write to a file.

Look up 
http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html

Comment: I'd be starting with recommending 3 arg open with lexical filehandles. Two argument is a bad idea for a lot of reasons.

Comment: Ok, my bad habits... Changed to 3-arg form.

Answer (score 2):

By default `open(INFO, $file) will take the file handle in read mode('<')` . So until unless you specify the `write mode('>')` you cannot print the values into the file . When you write the code you should use : use strict; and use warnings; which will be helpful.

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $InputFile = $ARGV[0];
open(FH,'<',"$InputFile")or die "Couldn't open the file $InputFile: $!";
my @file_content = <FH>; 
close(FH);
open(FH,'>',"$InputFile") or die "Cannot open $InputFile: $!";
#String to be added at the begining of the file
my $file = "test";  
print FH $file . "\n";
print FH @file_content;
close(FH);
```

Comment: I think the requester wants to insert data into the file, at the beginning. I think.